# Scaling the output of a segmentation model (UNet)

Tags: computer-vision, convolution, image-segmentation

So, I have to solve an instance segmentation problem and I am thinking of implementing a UNet model based on [Ronneberger et. al. 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) paper. The problem I have is that the output size has to be specific in order to train the model with the available data. My question is should I put in the effort to engineer the output of the model(20+ layers) to be in the size of my requirement or should I rescale the output using a rescaling algorithm from a pillow?